# black screen launching android

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, gluon

When I run my java fx on JVM (gradle run) everything works instead when I launch it on Android device (gradle AndroidInstall), I see a black screen, I don't have any error in console log.
My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'it.wstech.talco.TAMainApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:3.0.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: '../mglib/build/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: '../mglib/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: '../nowapp/build/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: '../nowapp/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])  

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'
    embeddedRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
         androidSdk="/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/Android/sdk"
         signingConfig {
            storeFile file('/opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/softws-keystore')
            storePassword 'wstechsrl'
            keyAlias 'ws-keystore'
            keyPassword 'xxxxx'
        }

    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'io.datafx.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

My console:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED
:compileEmbeddedJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaEmbedded SKIPPED
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED
:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE
:mergeClassesIntoJar
:validateManifest
:collectMultiDexComponents
:shrinkMultiDexComponents
:createMainDexList
:dex
:mergeAndroidAssets
:mergeAndroidResources
Crunching single PNG file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/src/android/res/mipmap-ldpi/ta_icon.png
        Output file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources/res/mipmap-ldpi-v4/ta_icon.png
Crunching single PNG file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/src/android/res/mipmap-hdpi/ta_icon.png
        Output file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources/res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ta_icon.png
Crunching single PNG file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/src/android/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ta_icon.png
        Output file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources/res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ta_icon.png
Crunching single PNG file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/src/android/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ta_icon.png
        Output file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ta_icon.png
Crunching single PNG file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/src/android/res/mipmap-mdpi/ta_icon.png
        Output file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources/res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ta_icon.png
Crunching single PNG file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/src/android/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ta_icon.png
        Output file: /opt/modja/workspace-fx/n_talco/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources/res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ta_icon.png
:processAndroidResources UP-TO-DATE
:processAndroidResourcesDebug
:validateSigningDebug
:apkDebug
:zipalignDebug
:androidInstall
Installed on device.
```

Comment: can you share your logcat also

Comment: I agree with @Shivam, there must be something wrong caught in logcat, plz find and fix exceptions in there.

Answer (score 0):

Check for permissions defined in Manifest file are allowed in the Application Manager->Your App -> Permissions .

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Instant run. It is because of the instant run.
disable it in settings and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the app Icons image size.Maybe the image size too large to process by android device. if the resolution is greater than 512*512 the processing time will be increased.